# How to generate Callable Wrapper(automatically) Xamarin Mono

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using an native lib for android via Java Bindings Library Project.   All goes fine,except one **method**(and i don't understand why,maybe he's incorrect ported from java to C#).

So the main idea,to make an workaround via ***Callable Wrapper***.
I have implemented Android project in native mode. In this project i also implemented java class(where i'm using this ***unlucky*** method) and what i need,just to know how to generate automatically Wrapper and how to add/use into my Mono project?

Or can i make an **.jar lib** on this native Android project and via bindings library add to my Xamarin.Android project?

PS Sorry for my eng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is to add new java class to OpenCV project. That class should contain methods you want to use ( e.g. to wrap FindContours()). Rebuild project and resulting JAR use in binding project in MonoDevelop/VS solution.

That way you'll call wrapped FindContours() method and it will return expected results :) .

Comment: Holy moly,you're right!!! Now i understand my mistake(with native project), AWESOME! All work fines and that is simple.
Congrats with +50 :) !